# Typedef declaration in the form `int typedef my_int;`

Tags: c++, typedef

To declare `my_int` as a type alias for `int` we can write:

```
typedef int my_int;   // (1)
```

Curiously, the following also seems to define an `int` alias:

```
int typedef my_int;   // (2)
```

I have never seen such syntax before. Why does it work?

Comment: Better, in modern C++: `using foo =bar;`.. stop using `typedef`.

Comment: Wow ! That's a nice one ! it's almost as strange as the equivalence of  p[i]  and i[p]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My reasoning after reading [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/declarations) is this: (1) and (2) are declarations of the form

```
specifiers-and-qualifiers declarators-and-initializers;
```

with `specifiers-and-qualifiers` being either `typedef int` or `int typedef`.

The order of specifiers and qualifiers doesn't matter, and both (1) and (2) are valid declarations of a type alias. For example, to define an alias for `const int` we can, in principle, use any of these 6 combinations:

```
typedef int const my_cint;
typedef const int my_cint;
int typedef const my_cint;
const typedef int my_cint;
int const typedef my_cint;
const int typedef my_cint;
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, your interpretation is correct as explained [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef):

> The typedef specifier, when used in a declaration's
>   decl-specifier-seq, specifies that the declaration is a typedef
>   declaration, and declares typedef-names rather than functions or
>   objects.

Nevertheless, in modern c++, the [type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) are better defined with a `using` clause:

```
using my_int = int;
```

It's not just a matter of style:  `typedef` don't support templatization whereas type alias do:

```
template <typename T>
using my_list = list<T>;   // not possible with typedef
...
my_list<double> numbers;
```