# can we use the C++ keyword "typename" without templates?

Tags: c++, header, typedef, typename

I saw this code in a header file.

```
using pointIndex = typename std::pair<std::vector<double>, size_t>;
```

1. Can we use "typename" here without a template?
2. Is it necessary to use typename here?
3. What is the difference between "typedef" and "typename"?

Comment: Obviously related reading: [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: One question per question, please. Are you facing some practical/actual problem? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typename` and `typedef` are completely different things.

**`typedef`** is a keyword used to introduce a *type alias* (a **type def**inition). In recent standards you can also use `using` for this. So:

```
typedef int MyThing;

// or
using MyThing = int;
```

**`typename`** is a keyword that says "the next thing is a type". It's used when dealing with templates in some situations, both in template declarations (e.g. `template <typename T> void foo() { /*..*/ }`) and [to help the parser along in some situations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords). In the example you've given, [it is valid, but redundant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename).

The two things are entirely different, and thus not interchangeable.

Comment: One [interesting feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58781929/typedef-declaration-in-the-form-int-typedef-my-int) of `typedef` is that its position doesn't matter: `typedef int MyThing;` and `int typedef MyThing;` are both correct. And for `const int` type alias there are six valid combinations.

Comment: @Evg For some value of "interesting" ;)

Comment: @Evg it's interesting. Thank you

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings thank you very much for your answer. It solves my question. But I have one question. Is it okay to replace above lone with this (without typename)?`using pointIndex = std::pair<std::vector<double>, size_t>;`

Comment: @Cham Try it and see!